# How to check if the URL contains a given string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How could I do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.contains("franky")) // This doesn't work, any suggestions?
    {
         alert("your url contains the name franky");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `"window.location.contains is not a function"`

Answer (score 843, accepted):

You need add href property and check `indexOf` instead of `contains`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("franky") > -1) {
      alert("your url contains the name franky");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have a long URL like this, http://preview.tbwabox.co.nz/_v005/index.html#buying-a-car and I want to check if the string has "buying-a-car but the script" isn't working?

Comment: @Vennsoh You're not able to find "buying-a-car" because you need to look in `window.location.hash` not `window.location.href`. Simply swap those values out in OP's function.

Comment: @J.W. Why` >-1` can't we use` >0`?

Comment: @Elshan Because, strictly speaking, `.href.indexOf("franky")` [can return a value of 0](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) if `.href` begins with "franky". Of course, in this case, it never does as `.href` always begins with the protocol, typically "http:" or "file:". Despite this, you should ALWAYS use >-1, >=0 or, my preference, !==-1 when comparing with the result of [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Comment: I have an array of value and want to see if the Url has any of the value and give me the index of the array that matches the condition. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: you can also use ~ (NOT operator) instead of checking > -1.

NOT operator turns -1 to 0 (false), in case of indexOf which returns the position of match so NOT operator returns a negative value (which is true, all values other than 0 is true).

0 = false
-1 = true
1 = true

eg: if(~window.location.href.indexOf('franky')) {
alert(' text goes here')
}

Comment: It will be a good practice if you convert your string to lower or uppercase as indexof() method is case sensitive. This will be if your search isn't case sensitive mind full

Answer (score 130):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("franky") != -1)
```

would do it. Alternatively, you could use a regexp:

```
if (/franky/.test(window.location.href))
```

Comment: A pros/cons between the two options would be a nice addition to this answer.

Comment: But if I used an regex expression nobody would be able to read it ;)

Comment: const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const path = url.pathname;
if (/^\/test($|\/|-)/.test(path)) {  
//do   
}

This is the way

Answer (score 37):

You would use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("franky") != -1){....}
```

Also notice the addition of `href` for the string otherwise you would do:

```
if(window.location.toString().indexOf("franky") != -1){....}
```

Answer (score 33):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) isn't a String, but it has a `toString()` method. So you can do it like this:

```
(''+window.location).includes("franky")
```

or

```
window.location.toString().includes("franky")
```

From the [old Mozilla docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120505074801/https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

> Location objects have a toString
>   method returning the current URL. You
>   can also assign a string to
>   window.location. This means that you
>   can work with window.location as if it
>   were a string in most cases.
>   Sometimes, for example when you need
>   to call a String method on it, you
>   have to explicitly call toString.

Comment: In Firefox 48, String.prototype.contains() has been removed. Use String.prototype.includes() only. [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @CaseyC Changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1) 
            {
                 alert("your url contains the name franky");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What's the difference between calling window.location.indexOf and window.location.href.indexOf?

Comment: @starsplusplus There isn't any difference. `window.location.href` is an alias of `window.location` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: The above one works fine for me but for two variable how to check its contains the both the values

Comment: @VinothNarayan You can simply add another condition to the `if` statement.

To make sure it has both, you can use the AND operator, which is `&&` in Javascript:

`if( window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf("box") > -1 )`

To check if it has one or the other value, use the OR operator, which is two pipe characters `||`

`if( window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1 || window.location.href.indexOf("box") > -1 )`

Answer (score 12):

The regex way:

```
var matches = !!location.href.match(/franky/); //a boolean value now
```

Or in a simple statement you could use:

```
if (location.href.match(/franky/)) {
```

I use this to test whether the website is running locally or on a server:

```
location.href.match(/(192.168|localhost).*:1337/)
```

This checks whether the *href* contains either `192.168` or `localhost` AND is followed by `:1337`.

As you can see, using regex has its advantages over the other solutions when the condition gets a bit trickier.

Comment: Nice. I used if (window.parent.location.href.match(/\?/)) {
 window.parent.location = window.parent.location.pathname;
} and it works very well...

Comment: Alternatively, it feels a bit more concise to me to use `if(/franky/.test(location.href)) { /* regex matched */ }` if I'm not doing anything with the matches.

Comment: Yeah, `test` is definitely cleaner than `match` in this case.

Answer (score 7):

`document.URL` should get you the `URL` and

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("searchtext") != -1) {
    //found
} else {
    //nope
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it's shorter and works exactly as `window.location.href`:

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("franky") > -1) { ... }
```

also if you want to check the previous URL:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf("franky") > -1) { ... }
```

Comment: @sixstarpro I didn't do the downvote, but, oh I don't know, maybe obviously because you gave the same answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923708/1961728) posted 18 months previously! Also, the extra info about `document.referrer` is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Easier it gets

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.includes('franky'))    //includes() method determines whether a string contains specified string.
    {
         alert("url contains franky");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

It will be a good practice if you convert your string to lower or uppercase as indexof() method is case sensitive.

This will be if your search isn't case sensitive you can simply use indexOf() method without converting the orignal string to lowercase or uppercase:

```
var string= location.href;
var convertedString= string.toLowerCase();

if(convertedString.indexOf('franky') != -1)
{
    alert("url has franky");
}
else
{
    alert("url has no franky");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I like this approach, instead.

```
top.location.pathname.includes('franky')
```

It works in many cases.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
    $(document).ready
    (
        function () 
        { 
            var regExp = /franky/g;
            var testString = "something.com/frankyssssddsdfjsdflk?franky";//Inyour case it would be window.location;
            if(regExp.test(testString)) // This doesn't work, any suggestions.                 
            {                      
                alert("your url contains the name franky");                 
            }             
        }
    );         
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try indexOf

```
if (foo.indexOf("franky") >= 0)
{
  ...
}
```

You can also try search (for regular expressions)

```
if (foo.search("franky") >= 0)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

a window location is an object that contains multiple methods and props some of them is strings related to URL so you can search for the targeted string safely:

```js
const href = location.href;
// "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string"

// another option 
const pathname = location.pathname;
// "/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string"

// search for string safely
pathname.includes("questions"); // true
href.includes("questions"); // true
```

[The Location Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp)

Answer (score 2):

> Use Window.location.href to take the url in javascript.  it's a
>   property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser.
>   Setting the property to something different will redirect the page.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('franky') > -1) {
     alert("your url contains the name franky");
}
```

Comment: How to check if a url is default page and string iam checking is not visible . like for example sample.com/homepage.aspx  is my page and iam looking for string 'homepage'.                  if((loc.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf('homepage') > -1)){} works fine but  when Iam on sample.com(which still points to homepage.aspx) above code will not work.How to check for this scenario as well?please help!

Answer (score 2):

I like to create a `boolean` and then use that in a logical `if`.

```
//kick unvalidated users to the login page
var onLoginPage = (window.location.href.indexOf("login") > -1);

if (!onLoginPage) {
  console.log('redirected to login page');
  window.location = "/login";
} else {
  console.log('already on the login page');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in your js file

```
                var url = window.location.href;
                console.log(url);
                console.log(~url.indexOf("#product-consulation"));
                if (~url.indexOf("#product-consulation")) {
                    console.log('YES');
                    // $('html, body').animate({
                    //     scrollTop: $('#header').offset().top - 80
                    // }, 1000);
                } else {
                    console.log('NOPE');
                }
```

Comment: I didn't know `~`, so I looked it up: **"`~` is a trick to turn `indexOf()`'s found return value into truthy (while making not-found as falsy). People otherwise use it for its side effect of truncating numbers..."** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12299678/3917091

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions will be more optimal for a lot of people because of word boundaries `\b` or similar devices. Word boundaries occur when any of `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` are on *that side* of the next match, or when an alphanumeric character connects to line or string end or beginning.

```
if (location.href.match(/(?:\b|_)franky(?:\b|_)))
```

If you use `if(window.location.href.indexOf("sam")`, you'll get matches for `flotsam` and `same`, among other words. `tom` would match tomato and tomorrow, without regex.

Making it case-sensitive is as simple as removing the `i`.

Further, adding other filters is as easy as

```
if (location.href.match(/(?:\b|_)(?:franky|bob|billy|john|steve)(?:\b|_)/i))
```

Let's talk about `(?:\b|_)`. RegEx typically defines `_` as a `word character` so it doesn't cause a word boundary. We use this `(?:\b|_)` to deal with this. To see if it either finds `\b` or `_` on either side of the string.

Other languages may need to use something like

```
if (location.href.match(/([^\wxxx]|^)(?:franky|bob|billy|john|steve)([^\wxxx]|$)/i))
//where xxx is a character representation (range or literal) of your language's alphanumeric characters.
```

All of this is easier than saying

```
var x = location.href // just used to shorten the code
x.indexOf("-sam-") || x.indexOf("-sam.") || x.indexOf(" sam,") || x.indexOf("/sam")...
// and other comparisons to see if the url ends with it 
// more for other filters like frank and billy
```

<sup>Other languages' flavors of Regular Expressions support `\p{L}` but javascript does not, which would make the task of detecting foreign characters much easier. Something like `[^\p{L}](filters|in|any|alphabet)[^\p{L}]`</sup>

Comment: The only down side to regular expressions is they are "write only" ( ie. Impossible to read)   ;)

Comment: @RayLoveless Yeah, in languages without `(?#comments)` and freespacing `# comments` like javascript. However, this one isn't difficult to read. // When I use a complex regex in javascript, I keep a commented copy that I can edit lol.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code ♥

```
function CheckUrl(url) {
var checkA = url.match(/(https|http):\/\/(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(.*?)(\/|'')/g);
var checkP = url.match(/(https|http):\/\/(.*?)\.(.*?)(\/|'')/g);
if (checkA != null || checkP != null) {
    return true;
}
else {
    console.log("Error", "The link is not valid");
}
return false;}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You can use javascript string method match

```js
const url = window.location.href;
const find = 'questions';
const found = url.match(find);

console.log(url);

if(found !== null && found[0] === find){
  console.log('You are in the questions page');
} else {
  console.log('You are not in the questions page');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this script

```
<div>
  <p id="response"><p>
  <script>
    var query = document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1);
    var text_input = query.split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=text_input;
  </script> </div>
```

And the url form is `www.localhost.com/web_form_response.html?text_input=stack&over=flow`

The text written to `<p id="response">` will be `stack`