# how to check if the url contains multiple strings. Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

In the question [how to check if the url contains a given string. Javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string-javascript-jquery)
the answer checks if the url contains a given string.  I want to extend this to check if it contains two things name=franky && gender=male.  I tried

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("name=franky" && "gender=male") > -1)
```

which appeared to work initially, but with further testing I have found it seems to work if only one of name or gender is present. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could break it into two parts and call indexOf twice instead of trying to check for both strings in the same call. Something like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("name=franky") > -1 && 
    window.location.href.indexOf("gender=male") > -1)
```

Comment: I tried something like this initially but didn't quite get the syntax right.

Answer (score 5):

The `.indexOf()` function only looks for a single string. To test for two strings you need two calls to `.indexOf()` as per Christofer's answer:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("name=franky") > -1 && 
   window.location.href.indexOf("gender=male") > -1)
```

The reason I'm posting an answer too is to briefly explain how the `&&` operator works: given `expr1 && expr2`, the [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Summary) *"Returns* `expr1` *if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns* `expr2`."

What does "converted to false" mean? Basically `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN` and `""` (empty string) are "falsy" and will be "converted to false". non-zero numbers, non-empty strings and any object are "truthy" and will be converted to true.

That means when you said `"name=franky" && "gender=male"` the `&&` operator tests the first operand, finds that (in this case) it *can't* be converted to false, so it returns `"gender=male"`. So the reason your code seemed to work some of the time is that in effect it was doing this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("gender=male") > -1)
```

Comment: +1'ed for the explanation. I was just about to post that as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Another generic approach

```
function CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(url, qsCollection) {
    for (var i = 0; i < qsCollection.length; i++) {
        if (url.indexOf(qsCollection[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Call it like this.

```
var myUrl = window.location.href;
var queryStrings = ["name=franky", "gender=male"];
var allPresent = CheckIfAllQueryStringsExist(myUrl, queryStrings);
```