# Check to see a URL contains a certain character how many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Something similar to this, [How to check if the URL contains a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string)

but is there a way to check if the URL contains a slash (/) more than 3 times, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply grab the string, perform a match for `/`, then use `.length` to count the matches.

Comment: what part are you stuck on? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

This is one possibility, all characters that are not "/" are removed, then the [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is used to find how many characters remain.

Javascript

```
var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449482/check-to-see-a-url-contains-a-certain-character-how-many-times";

console.log(url.replace(/[^\/]/g, "").length);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8VUrh/)

This is not the fastest method though, I just wanted to give an alternative to those that have already been suggested in a previous [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881085/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-javascript). I added it to the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/count-the-number-of-occurances-in-string/18)