# Tumblr: how do I remove the description/sidebar box on the submit page in the default Peter Vidani theme?

Tags: themes, submit, tumblr, sidebar

I have a tumblr account that has submission enabled, and I have a short description with a form in the "description" area that appears on the sidebar. However, this description also appears on myblog.tumblr.com/submit. I'd like to remove it.

I looked at the documentation on http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#navigation, but haven't been able to figure out how to prevent the sidebar description from showing at the top of the submit page.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. But if I did, a work around would be using jQuery to check if the current url contains the string /submit and simply disable the sidebar, or the element that contains the description.

I don't know jQuery but I know it's possible. I'd suggest you to look into this post:
[How to check if the URL contains a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string)
and combine it with this line (replace the "alert part")

```
$("#sidebardescription).hide();
```

Another solution would be if Tumblr provided you with a way to only render for specific pages. They usually do that. I'd look into this part {block:SubmissionsEnabled} {/block:SubmissionsEnabled} before I go with the workaround.