# JQuery changing class of element with id or class based on page url/name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="header-content" class="header-content">...</div>
```

Jquery

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {



      var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
      if(/$/.test(loc)) { // If Empty or if just home URL
        $('#header-content').addClass('home-page');
        //Remove All Other Classes
        $('#header-content').removeClass('start-here');
        $('#header-content').removeClass('work-with-me');
      }
      if(/start-here$/.test(loc)) { // if page = root/start-here/
        $('#header-content').addClass('start-here');
        //Remove All Other Classes
        $('#header-content').removeClass('home-page');
        $('#header-content').removeClass('work-with-me');
      }
      if(/work-with-me$/.test(loc)) { // if page = root/work-with-me/
        $('#header-content').addClass('work-with-me');
        //Remove All Other Classes
        $('#header-content').removeClass('home-page');
        $('#header-content').removeClass('start-here');
      }


    });
```

URL Example: 
http://www.somedomain.com/the-page/

What I'd like to do is have the script identify the text "the-page" in the url and if it's a match assign the class. As you can see in my sample jquery code, I'm trying to assign classes to the home page, start-here page and work-with-me page.

I'm not sure how to modify the above Jquery so it will work with the URL Example format.

As well how would I detect if it was the index page and the URL looked like this: http://www.somedomain.com/ with no page name on the end?

Comment: if I use a file name, like page.php and put that in the code like this `if(/start-here.php$/.test(loc)) { // if page = root/start-here/` it will work with that no issues. With the .php on the end it works with a static site I built, but as I said can't get it to work with the directory type page names.

Comment: For a start, `/$/.test(...)` will be true for **any** string, as all strings have an ending.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Crowder. I'm kind of a newb at this. I don't understand why I can't just add a "/" and drop the .php and have it work with the URL format (http://www.somedomain.com/page-name/)

Comment: basically want I want to do is when the page is loaded have the script check to see if the page has the name wrapped in /'s. So I want it to look for "/page-name/" with both forward slashes. and if it matches that assign the class.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string

Comment: I tried it by removing the $ but no luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming the domain is known, it should be doable with this:

```
//you'll of course want to get this via window.location.href instead:
var exLoc = "http://www.somedomain.com/the-page/";

var root = "somedomain.com";
var end = exLoc.slice(exLoc.lastIndexOf(root)+root.length);

//end is your "text" at the end of your domain (somedomain.com in this case)
```

Which, using your example would look something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
  var root = "somedomain.com";
  var end = loc.slice(loc.lastIndexOf(root)+root.length);

  if(end.length <= 0) { // If Empty or if just home URL
    $('#header-content').addClass('home-page');
    //Remove All Other Classes
    $('#header-content').removeClass('start-here');
    $('#header-content').removeClass('work-with-me');
  }
  if(end === "/start-here/") { // if page = root/start-here/
    $('#header-content').addClass('start-here');
    //Remove All Other Classes
    $('#header-content').removeClass('home-page');
    $('#header-content').removeClass('work-with-me');
  }
  if(end === "/work-with-me/") { // if page = root/work-with-me/
    $('#header-content').addClass('work-with-me');
    //Remove All Other Classes
    $('#header-content').removeClass('home-page');
    $('#header-content').removeClass('start-here');
  }


});
```

Comment: I'd like to modify the code I have above to work with your solution. Can you show me how your code would work with the code above?

Comment: modified my answer to include your example

Comment: @JeremyBrown if my answer solved your problem, could you please mark it as such?

Comment: Now I'm just trying to figure out what all the code does, still learning. Thanks again for the help on this.

Comment: Actually, this code
` if(end.length <= 0) { // If Empty or if just home URL`
    doesn't apply a class to home page.

Comment: Figured out what it was. The code end.length <= 0 I changed to a 1 and now it works.

Comment: Indeed, that just checks if the length of "end" is 0, ie you are at the "root" level of the webpage.

Yes maybe you need it to be one to catch a trailing "/" sign. You're welcome, in any case.