# IF URL = xxx then show text in cshtml mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have two mvc applications with cshtml views, both with a different url. They are acceptatance and production apps. I need to alter/hide some text on the homeview depending on the url. So for example: If the URL contains the word "production" i need to add the text "PRODUCTION" to a div on the homescreen.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string you may use this answers as your div element.

Comment: if your only option is to read from URL then read the Request.Uri in your controller action and pass your environment name to your view. Ideally, you should either have a config setting for such things.

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewBags. Declare ViewBag in controller for example:

```
ViewBag.Type = "Production"
```

on production page, and:

```
ViewBag.Type = "Other Type"
```

in other method in controller. Then in homeview check what is under this ViewBag.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Type))
{
    if (ViewBag.Type == "Production")
    {
        <p>Production</p>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Type == "Other Type")
    {
        <p>Other Type</p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is better way of doing this.

you could use web.config transform that way you will have different config files for test and production.

in web.config create  appsetting

```
<appSettings>
            <add key="Environment" value="Test" />
</appSettings>
```

in cshtml check key value and do stuff

```
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment")) && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Environment") == "Test")
{

}
```