# shareable URLs when displaying page content via jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I am working on a static webpage that hides/shows particular sections of content when according buttons are clicked (I should mention I'm very new to jQuery).

As of now, it is not possible to directly visit a section by means of an URL. Is there a way to achieve this?

For instance, visiting http://www.mypage.com/#contact would automatically show the according section/div (and hide all others).

thanks!

HTML:

```
<a href="#home" id="button_home">Home</a>
<a href="#contact" id="button_contact">Contact</a> 

<div id="section_home">some text</div>
<div id="section_contact">some text</div>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#button_home").click(function(){
          $("#section_home").addClass("visible");
          $("#section_contact").removeClass("visible");
      });

      $("#button_contact").click(function(){
          $("#section_home").removeClass("visible");
          $("#section_contact").addClass("visible");
      });
   });
```

Comment: The `hcontact` class inside `<div id="section_hcontact">some text</div>` is a misstake right?

Comment: thanks David, yes it is... fixed it!

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4Ljw9zo/

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#button_home").click(function(){
          $("#section_home").addClass("visible");
          $("#section_contact").removeClass("visible");
      });

      $("#button_contact").click(function(){
          $("#section_home").removeClass("visible");
          $("#section_contact").addClass("visible");
      });
   });
```

```css
.section{
  display: none;
}
.section.visible{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#home" id="button_home">Home</a>
<a href="#contact" id="button_contact">Contact</a> 

<div class="section" id="section_home">Section Home</div>
<div class="section" id="section_contact">Section Contact</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but no... hiding and showing sections works fine. i'd like to be able to share an URL to instance the "contact" section.. therefore i need to find a way to (only) show this section when the page is visited by a link such as http://www.mypage.com/#contact

... sorry for not making myself clear enough

Comment: Maybe you could check the url if it contains for example the `#contact` string and if so, add `visible` class to the contact section.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string