# Website functionality depending if it was accessed via QR code or not

Tags: javascript, html

im new on stackoverflow, so don't be harsh xD

Im still learning and there is so much that i dont know yet

Im currently developing a website and got stuck with a question:
how to make a website perform differently if it was accessed via a QR code?

For example if a person gets to a website through QR code they can see a button, but if a person gets to a website through copying url or searching through the web, then there is no button.

I have looked through the web, W3 and stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything that could be similar, hence thats the reason why im here =)

The only thing that i found was (see below), however im not sure it has any use for my idea

```
var referrer = document.referrer
```

I dont use php and have no idea of how to use it, hence no php please =)

Comment: Make the URL that the QR code generates include a query parameter, and check for that.

Comment: No method will be bullet-proof, since users can always force the browser to send anything they want in the request.

Comment: Add a string to your url and detect it with js like mysit.com/qrcode and use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string

Comment: Scanning the QR code and telling the app to open the link will be no different from somebody typing the URL into a browser's address bar manually as far as the referrer is concerned, so a very basic way would be to add something like `?qr=yes` to the end of the URL. This can be detected by PHP/node/whatever your server is using or client-side JS. However it can of course easily be added manually. If this is just for statistical purposes or something, that should be fine.

Comment: @ChrisG He stated, no php/