# Add a class to a page element contained in a particular url

Tags: javascript, css, url, titlebar

I want to create a class for the title bars of pages that contain a certain piece of url.
My url is [www.domainname.com/poste/XXX](http://www.domainname.com/poste/XXX) and I want to add the class only if the part after the .com contains only /poste/.  I've seen examples for "contains this term" but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.
The existing class for the title bar is: .fusion-page-title-bar
Thanks in advance for the help and advice!

Comment: [How to check if the URL contains a given string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string) and [How to add a class to a given element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-to-add-a-class-to-a-given-element)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yes ! But how do I proceed for my application which is "contains only /poste/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if a url contains any string, do the following:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf(".com/poste") > -1) {
       // do something
}
```

(checking if the index of a string is bigger than -1 is like asking if he is in there)

to conditonally add class:

```
element.classList.add("my-class");
```

combined it would be:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf(".com/poste") > -1) {
       titleClass = document.querySelector(".your-title-class");
       titleClass.classList.add("conditionalClass");
}
```

*there are other solutions using jquery (like the one in @Wimanicesir comment), but it personaly prefer not using it :)

Comment: Both solutions provided in the comment are also without jQuery :) The first one has jQuery in it, but it's just used for the document ready. The important code is all vanilla JS. Even more, all the code you used here can be found back literately in those two posts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem is that you want to check if the URL **ends** with /poste/.

You can use the string function endsWith().

```js
  var url = window.location.href
  console.log('Current url: ', url)
  
  if (url.endsWith("js")) {
    console.log('The url ends with js');
  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith